# How to avoid IFormFile dependency in Application layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, clean-architecture

All my DTOs are in the application layer, but one of them needs to be able to accept images, as IFormFile, so it looks somewhat like this.

```
public class SiteSettingsDto
{
    public long Color1 { get; set; }
    public long Color2 { get; set; }
    public string CompetitionName { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

But that approach makes the application layer depend on ***Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http***, which as I understand, breaks the rules of clean architecture.

What I found to work is passing in the DTO and IFormFile to the controller separately

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddSettings([FromForm]SiteSettingsDto settingsDto, IFormFile image)
```

But I feel like that defeats the purpose of using DTOs. Is there a better solution to this, than what I've came up with?

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `IFormFile` with `Stream` in your DTO.  The former represents an image file, you say.  Then it is binary data.  Then you can simply pass on a stream; you can choose from a [few methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-7.0#methods) to obtain the `IFormFile`'s stream.  If you don't like streams because is not "dumb data", then use a byte array.  Get the `IFormFile`'s stream, then store the contents in a byte array and pass that array.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many options.

## `IFormFile` as a separate controller action method parameter

What you have came up with might be the easiest way.

## `IFormFile` in your DTO

Map the DTO to another type and pass that type further.

## Avoid using `IFormFile`.

Create a backend DTO that will be automatically validated:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class UploadedFile
{
    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,png")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1_048_576)]
    public byte[] Contents { get; set; }
}
```

Create the frontend DTO:

```js
export interface UploadedFile {
  fileName: string;
  contents: string;
}
```

Then the frontend can create this DTO and initialize its `contents` property with the Base64-encoded version of the form file contents, e.g. using [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). The actual Base64-encoded content part starts after the comma, e.g. `data:image/jpeg;base64,........`